# $scope how to use variable in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular JS.  Below is my Angular code

```
$scope.remove = function (index) {

            var name = $scope.data.Filters[index].FilterName;  

            // value of name = 'AAAA' or 'BBBB' and so on 

            $scope. data. Filters. splice (index, 1);
            $scope.Json = angular.toJson($scope.data);
        };
```

And my HTML is

```
<div><small>{{AAAA}}</small></div>
<div><small>{{BBBB}}</small></div>
<select class="BBBB"> <option> .... </select>
<select class="AAAA"> <option> .... </select>
```

Based on the value of **name**  i want to reset the {{ }} vale in my view.

Say for an example 
**Example**

reset the value of {{AAAA}} if name = AAAA

so how can i use the variable name like below **UPDATED**

```
var name = $scope.data.Filters[index].FilterName;
$scope.name = "" /// How can i do like this 
$(name).selectpicker('deselectAll');
```

Can anyone help me

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use bracket notation for this. Using it you can target property of the object with the name stored in variable:

```
$scope[name] = '';
```

Comment: Wow. i am out of mind and It solved my problem. Simple solutions are always difficult find. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it helped you. When you use dot notation like `$scope.name` it's interpreted literally as property `name` of the object `$scope`. With bracket syntax you can provide any variable name.

Comment: Ho can i use the $(name).selectpicker('deselectAll'); it ??

Comment: I'm confused. What is `name` then if you use it like CSS selector?

Comment: I have updated the post. <select class="BBBB"> <option> .... </select> I want to rest this value also

Comment: Then try `$('.' + name).selectpicker('deselectAll');` but be aware that mixing jQuery with angular like this is not very good practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the value of name you can either do this:

```
<div><small ng-bind="name"></small></div>
```

Or you can do this:

```
<div><small>{{name}}</small></div>
```